# Javascript : Auto calculate sum with different type of input

Tags: javascript, sum

I have an ajax code which is concepted from [auto calculate the sum of input values with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133264/auto-calculate-the-sum-of-input-values-with-javascript). So I'd like to add more field to meet my needs. Then I added some inputs[checkbox] with given value in it. The idea is when the box is checked. Its value will be calculated to the process just like type in the input[text].

Here's the code :

```
<script language="javascript">
function AddInputs()
{
    var total = 0;
    var coll = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for ( var i = 0; i<coll.length; i++)
    {
        var ele = coll[i];
        total += parseInt(ele.value);
    }
    var Display = document.getElementById("Display");
    Display.innerHTML = total;
}
</script>
```

Here's the form:

```
<input onkeyup="AddInputs()" />
<input onkeyup="AddInputs()" />
<input onkeyup="AddInputs()" />
<input type="checkbox" onkeyup="AddInputs()" value="100" />
<span id="Display"></span>
```

The problem is I can't make the checkbox to get calculated with those input boxes. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `onkeyup` event is fired when you release a key on the keyboard and this doesn't happen when you click the checkbox. You should use either `onchange` (but this won't work in older IEs) or `onclick`.

Also note that the value of `100` will always be added to `total`. If you want to count the checkbox only if it's checked, use something like

```
if (ele.type !== 'checkbox' || ele.checked) {
    total += parseInt(ele.value);
}
```

Comment: Your method doesn't works:

`code <script language="javascript">
function AddInputs()
{
    var total = 0;
    var coll = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for ( var i = 0; i<coll.length; i++)
    {
  if (ele.type !== 'checkbox' || ele.checked) {
   total += parseInt(ele.value);
  }
    }
    var Display = document.getElementById("Display");
    Display.innerHTML = total;
}
</script>

<input onkeyup="AddInputs()" />
<input onkeyup="AddInputs()" />
<input onkeyup="AddInputs()" />
<input type="checkbox" onkeyup="AddInputs()" value="100" />+100
<span id="Display"></span>
`